# code runs much more slowly on java 7u55 than prior versions?

Tags: java, performance

I have a java application that runs from a jar file.  I have a user who upgraded his mac to java 7u55 and says that the application is now running substantially more slowly than previously.  I don't know which version of Java he had installed previously.  I believe the jar file was generated using the 7u51 JDK.  Any idea why this should be the case?  Might it help to recompile the application with the newer Java version?

Comment: Can you reproduce their problem on your computer? That would be a good first step, and then you can profile it.

Comment: As mentioned in response to @Stephen-C, I don't have access to the same hardware, which makes analysis challenging.  And profiling is not at all my area of expertise.  I was rather hoping that someone would say that there is some specific known issue with 7u55, preferably with a known fix, but I guess that was hoping too much! :D

Answer (score 1):

Recompiling is unlikely to make any difference.  The `javac` bytecode compiler does minimal optimization, and that is highly unlikely to change from one minor version to the next.  The clever optimization stuff is all done by the JIT compiler ... which is part of the JRE the user is running.

---

In general, it is impossible to say what is causing this slowdown:

- It might be the JVM.
- It might be something in your application.
- It might be that the user is now using your application for larger or qualitatively different problems.
- It might be something "external"; e.g. the user has reinstalled your software on a different file system, or is (maybe unwittingly) running more stuff on his Mac that is causing extra resource contention.
- It might be in your user's imagination.  (Yea ...)

---

So what can you do?

First, I think you need to reproduce the user's current setup, run his problems, and see if your application performs the same for you as for him.  If not, then you need access to the user's machine to figure out what is wrong with / on it.

Second, try profiling your application in the context of the user's setup / problem ... on your reproduction of the system.

If you don't have suitable hardware, you are kind of stuck ... but at least you have a reason for not being able to help the user further.

Comment: I don't have a Mac, which makes reproducing this more of a challenge.  I'm also not physically in the same location as the user but am hundreds of miles away, so sitting down at his computer is also not an option.  I haven't tried it under 7u55 on my PC yet but I'm guessing that that won't reproduce the issue.  

I know he's not using it for different problems, and I'm fairly certain it's not just his imagination.  

My suspicion is "something external" though that will be hard to track down or prove.

Comment: @PurpleVermont - Yea well, unless someone can provide you with the hardware to try to reproduce the user's problem, there is little you can do to investigate.

Comment: @PurpleVermont: IMHO the chances you can reproduce the problem without a Mac are pretty good; I'd give it a try. Consider also something like TeamViever which doesn't care about a few hundreds miles.

Comment: @maaartinus - I'm doubtful of the chances.  But I agree with you that it is worth a try.